# How to create a scroll section that I can add buttons to on runtime?

Tags: c#, winforms

I am new to the winforms and want to create an application that will have a scroll section which I need to make for the buttons which I will add on runtime.

The user will press an add button to add a button containing data which will then be used for the title, description. I need the button to be added to the scroll section and to be automatically placed under the last button in the section so it is organized and so I can scroll up and down through the section.

Like the image has with the scroll bar and the buttons:

[image]

How do I solve the problem?

Comment: Did you also give a look at **WPF**? It allows easier custom UI design, with vector graphics. https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/vs/features/wpf/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a `FlowLayoutPanel` with the following properties set:

```
AutoScroll = true;
FlowDirection = FlowDirection.TopDown;
WrapContents = false;
```

Once you do that, you can add buttons (or any control) to the `Controls` collection and it should flow from top to bottom and cause vertical scrollbars to appear once you fill the space.

Note, that it is quite difficult (or virtually impossible) to make a WinForms app look as nice as the one you provided an example of.  You would probably be better off using WPF.  But my answer should at least solve your particular problem with WinForms.